# How to submit input to node js service from react JS UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have general question regarding react js. I am very new in react. General approach in react is create a state object for input controls and assign its state value to that input before submitting. This will work fine when we have 2-5 controls on page.

I have 20 diff types of input present on page like textboxes, dropdowns, calender and radio button. Do I need to create 20 properties in state object? Do I need to write 20 diff types of onChange function for controls? This will my code too much lenghty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Controlled Inputs

You're dealing with **controlled inputs**. You can achieve the same with  **uncontrolled inputs** if you don't need to keep the state (at the bottom you will find a link that will help you with this).

To handle the inputs you need, one could do something like this:

**IMPORTANT: Notice that the state property match the input name.**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
    checkbox: false,
    dropdown: "",
    date: "",
    radio: ""
  };

  handleTextChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    const { name } = event.target;
    this.setState(previousState => ({ [name]: !previousState[name] }));
  };

  handleDropdownChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleDateChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleRadioChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Text</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="text"
          onChange={this.handleTextChange}
          value={this.state.text}
        />

        <p>Checkbox</p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="checkbox"
          onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
          value={this.state.checkbox}
        />

        <p>Dropdown</p>
        <select
          name="dropdown"
          value={this.state.dropdown}
          onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}
        >
          <option name="option1">Option 1</option>
          <option name="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>

        <p>Date</p>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="date"
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />

        <p>Radio</p>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
          value="option1"
        />
        <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
        <br />

        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
          value="option2"
        />
        <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you could simply add more inputs of one of these types carefully matching the input `name` to the class state `property.

You can find a working example in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-inputs-jttq8

For a more detailed answer and how to deal with uncontrolled forms, refer to this awesome article on medium: https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/the-complete-guide-to-forms-in-react-d2ba93f32825

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: What about properties in state object. Do I need to write 20 properties in state object on component. Thanks in advance. Do I not need to write in below way.  <Input
  name='username' value = {this.props.username}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>

Comment: If you need that as a component state, yes, you should specify all the initial state for each input. If you don't, you can use an HTML Form `onSubmit` method.

The main thing here is the `name` property: It will be provided within the event's target. And all the user input names should be present as state properties. I'll add this information to my answer.

Comment: If you need help creating other input handlers, let me know.

Comment: I did not get the meaning of line--> If you need that as a component state, yes. What if I dont declare that component state object  and just want to submit the values from input fields. Will it work.   It would great if you please help with other input handlers as well with pseudo code or so. Thank you very much.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check if you have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. So at the end I have to add 20 properties in state object? Is that right?